# Recall To Someone

Tags: word-meaning

I have a question about the usage of the verb "*recall*" [here](https://www.yahoo.com/health/womans-painful-story-details-health-risks-122200853917.html):

> She also suffered severe swelling below the knees in both legs, so much so that doctors had to cut her jeans off the previous day.  ***She recalled to doctors that*** the issues had begun the day before, when she was helping a relative move and spent hours squatting to empty cupboards. She’d been wearing skinny jeans at the time, and remembered they grew increasingly snug and uncomfortable the longer she had them on.

According to many dictionaries, "*recall*" means "*remember*".  So, if a person could "*recall to*" another person about some event, does that mean I could write:

> She ***remembered to*** doctors that the issues had begun the day before.

?

Answer (score 3):

To recall something (to yourself) can be used the same as to remember something, but recalled in this sense means that she is "re-telling" the story from her memory, which implies that she is remembering AND then telling someone else about it.

"Remembered to" doesn't work because remembering is an act you can only do to yourself.

Comment: It still sounds awkward. I think for the meaning of "re-telling" I'd go with "she _recounted_ to the doctors the issues" and for the meaning remembering "she _reminded_ the doctors of the issues"